# C Program Syntax (not compiling)

Tags: c, pointers, syntax

#### bst.c

```
//my bst.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "bst.h"
// Input: 뭩ize? size of an array
// Output: a pointer to an allocated array
// Effect: dynamically allocate an array of size+1 float-point numbers
//         the first slot of the array contains size+0.5
//         all the other slots contain -1;
BStree bstree_ini(int size) {
     int * BStree;
     BStree = (int *) malloc ((size+1)*sizeof(float)); //?
     BStree[0]=size+0.5; //?????
     int i;
     for (i=0; i<size; i++){
         BStree[i]=-1;
     }
     return *BStree;
}
```

#### bst.h

This header is provided by the professor and cannot be changed.

```
typedef float* BStree;
const float my_epsilon = 0.0001;
BStree bstree_ini(int size);
void bstree_insert(BStree bst, float key);
void bstree_traversal(BStree bst);
void bstree_free(BStree bst);
```

#### Problem

When I compile, it gives me this error: http://puu.sh/7y0Lp.png (the error is within the return statement for my first function). Does anyone know how to fix this? I apologize for posting a very simple question haha, I'm still quite new to C and pointers!

#### Rest of the code

Here's the rest of the `bst.c` that I haven't yet finished.

```
// Input: 뭕st? a binary search tree
// 뭟ey? a non-negative floating-point number
// Effect: key is inserted into bst if it is not already in bst
void bstree_insert(BStree bst, float key) {

}
// Input: 뭕st? a binary search tree
// Effect: print all the numbers in bst using in order traversal
void bstree_traversal(BStree bst) {

}
// Input: 뭕st? a binary search tree
// Effect: memory pointed to by bst is freed
void bstree_free(BStree bst) {

}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but the first letter in the variable names in your comments is coming out as some kind of east Asian character (뭕) rather than as a 'b', 'k', or 's'.

Comment: @Emmet: AFAICT, it's a Hangul Syllable U+BB55 (UTF-8 representation 0xEB 0xAD 0x95).  That doesn't make me much wiser, either.

Comment: It seems that there are actually three different ones ([뭩,뭕, and 뭟](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangul_consonant_and_vowel_tables#gg)), which I missed the first time.

Comment: My font is in Korean, that might be why. Not sure why it came out like that when I copy and pasted, but it's definitely a problem with my font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first visible definition is confused, if not confusing:

```
BStree bstree_ini(int size) {
     int * BStree;
```

The first line says that `bstree_ini()` is a function that takes an `int` argument and returns a `BStree`.

The second line says that `BStree` is a local variable of type `int *`.

You can't have both at once.  Since you return `*BStree`, the local variable is of the wrong type.

#### Second attempt

Since `bstree_ini()` needs to return a pointer to an array of floats, you can write:

```
BStree bstree_ini(int size)
{
     BStree;
     BStree data = malloc ((size + 1) * sizeof(*data));
     data[0] = size + 0.5;
     for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
         data[i] = -1.0;
     return data;
}
```

I remain to be convinced by the design, but given that you can't change the header, this should do the trick for you.

#### First attempt

This was provided as a possible answer before the confession that the header can't be changed.

The header defines:

```
typedef float *BStree;
```

which is a type I would not expect you to be using.  You would normally be using a structure type:

```
typedef struct BStree
{
    float      value;
    struct BStree *l_child;
    struct BStree *r_child;
} BStree;
```

In your function, you'd then have:

```
BStree *bstree_ini(int size)
{
    BStree *bp = …;
    …
    return bp;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But you changed the typedef float *BStree; , I'm not allowed to change that. My prof gave us the header file and we have to write our code to work based on that.

Comment: Such rules **must** be stated in the question or it really annoys people who answer in good faith.  Is this supposed to be a binary search tree?  Or is it something else?

Comment: Sorry about that! I'm new to this board as well :(

it's supposed to be a binary search tree using arrays.

Comment: OK; you've got the lecture notes, so presumably you can do the job.  I imagine that you'll be creating a heap organized so that the left child of node `i` (for `i` >= 1; node 0 is not used) is in node `2*i` and the right child is in `2*i+1` (and the parent of a node `i > 1` is in node `i/2`).  See Bentley 'Programming Pearls' and/or 'More Programming Pearls' for a discussion of this organization as a 'heap' (rather than a BST per se — though it can be used as a BST).

Answer (score 1):

Your functions prototype says it returns something with TYPE BStree, which is pointer to a float, but you try to return an integer that VARIABLE BStree is pointing to.

So you return an int instead of a pointer to a float.

```
BStree bstree_ini(int size) {
    ...
    return *BStree;
}
```

You call both a type and a variable BStree. That's extremely confusing. Fix that first.

Comment: BStree is a binary search tree using arrays. How do I return the array that I made within the first function? It needs to be a pointer to that thing!

Comment: He's not trying to return a pointer, he's dereferencing the pointer in the `return` statement, so he would only be returning a pointer if `BStree` was (at least) a pointer to a pointer, which it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

You say `typedef float* BStree;`  which means that BStree 'objects' are actually pointers. 
The warning is due to the fact that you returned an `int` pointer while the compiler expected a `float` pointer (== BSTree)

```
BStree bstree_ini(int size) {
  BStree tree;
  tree = (BStree) malloc ((size+1)*sizeof(float)); /* Make size +1 places to store a float */ 
  tree[0]=0.5 + (float)size; /* cast size to float */
  int i;
  for (i=1; i<=size; i++){ /*you need to start at 1 or you'll overwrite size+0.5*/
      tree[i]=-1.0; 
  }
  return tree; /* returning a pointer to a float* (or a BSTree)*/
}
```

Note that I did not dereference `tree`; it is already a pointer